# call to a member function on null Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating something more like a facebook post , i get a post from user and store it to database for now. I have created two models **User and Post**

here is the code of User model

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Eloquent implements Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Here is the code of Post model

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()

    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

and I have a postController and here is the code of it

```
    use App\Post;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function createPost(Request $request)
    {

        $post = new Post();

        $post->userpost = $request['userpost'];
        $request->user()->posts()->save($post);  -> **Error here Call to a member function posts() on null**
        return redirect()->back();

    }}
```

Comment: The question being?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is indicating that `$request->user()` returned `null`, which means that the user is not logged in to the application – i.e is a guest. The method `$request->user()` will only return a user, if a user is authenticated.

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication):

> once a user is authenticated, you may access the authenticated user via an Illuminate\Http\Request instance

The solution is to wrap your code in an auth check like below, or use middleware to prevent access to this route unless the user is authenticated.

```
if(\Auth::check()){
    $post = new Post();

    $post->userpost = $request['userpost'];
    $request->user()->posts()->save($post);
} else {
    // not logged in - do something
}
```

Comment: recently i updated Voyager admin and this solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
use App\Post;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PostController extends Controller
{

  public function createPost(Request $request)
    {

    $post = new Post();
    $post->userpost = $request['userpost'];
    $post->user_id = LOGGED_IN_USER_ID; 
    //$request->user()->posts()->save($post);
    $post->save();
    return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: If i follow this , only the post gets stored to the database without the user ID (NULL user id) , i want to store it along with the user id

Comment: You have to pass logged user id to this function

Comment: user_id column is must in posts table

Comment: user_id column is there in post table but it is filled with '0' but the current logged in user id is different

Comment: You can use $post->user_id = LOGGED_IN_USER_ID;